# Load images before jQuery function ask for them

Tags: javascript, jquery

In my wordpress site i am using a quite simple jQuery piece of code:

```
jQuery(".first-sq").mouseenter(function(){
      jQuery(".first-sq img").attr('srcset', '/wp-content/uploads/2017/01/MachineLearning_hoverx2.png');
 })
 jQuery(".first-sq").mouseleave(function(){
   jQuery(".first-sq img").attr('srcset' , '/wp-content/uploads/2017/01/MachineLearningx2.png');
 })
```

Now the code works but the problem is when `mouseenter` called it takes some time for the image to load, and you can see it being loaded. or in other words, the image revealed in portions. Is there a way to load all the images the document might use ,when document load, so when in situations like my `mouseenter` the image will show immediately and wont have to load?

Comment: Preload the images, check this [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/476679/preloading-images-with-jquery) for answers on how to do this

Comment: Search engine of your choice -> javascript image preload

Comment: You can preload images using JavaScript, but a better way is to combine both images into a single one, set is as `background-image` of a `div` and shift the position. Keyword: `css sprites`

Comment: Why don't you use jQuery onload function to load the images and then on mouseenter just change the display style to none / block ?

Answer (score 0):

You could achieve this by preload images. Try something like that:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  $('<img src="/wp-content/uploads/2017/01/MachineLearning_hoverx2.png">');
  $('<img src="/wp-content/uploads/2017/01/MachineLearningx2.png">');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Copy of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/476679/preloading-images-with-jquery?rq=1)

```
function preload(arrayOfImages) {
    $(arrayOfImages).each(function(){
        $('<img/>')[0].src = this;
    });
}

// Usage:
preload([
    'img/img1.jpg'
]);
```

Comment: Please don't [plagiarise answers](http://stackoverflow.com/a/476681/519413). If you reference another answer at least leave the original author a credit. You can also vote to close the question as a duplicate if you feel it's warranted, which would seem to be the case here

Comment: I did post it as a copy with a link ...:| I just didn't like the blah blah so I removed that...And I was unaware about the duplicate thing.

Comment: No problem, just thought I'd let you know for future reference